# Rebar release, app options config

Tags: erlang, release, rebar

I have this on my Makefile:

```
CONFIG ?= "apps/${NODE}/priv/app.config"
RUN := erl -pa apps/${NODE}/ebin -pa deps/*/ebin -smp enable -s lager -boot start_sasl -config ${CONFIG} ${ERL_ARGS}
```

How do I pass the `-config apps/appname/priv/app.config` and `-s lager` options while using `rebar generate`

I suspect it goes somewhere in reltool.config but not sure where ?

Also, to clarify, 'rebar generate' works fine but when launching the generated version from the bin folder the error has to do with the config not being loaded.

Comment: Including the option at runtime like this: ./bin/appname console -config lib/appname-0.2/priv/app.config 
works fine it seems. This is also okay, but am I missing something that would include the option as part of the release ? Overlay variables seem like something to look into as well

Comment: After yet more digging I can see how the final config is built. http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html

It's basically a merge of app.config in my 'priv' folder and sys.config in $ROOT/releases/Vsn
The question is; how does sys.config end up there from my source files ? Can I put a sys.config somewhere in my source and it will be picked up ?

Answer (score 0):

These flags normally go in the vm.args file.

It can be generated by running `rebar create-node`, the full tutorial for rebar is here: https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Release-handling